# Deny an access to edit/delete a post, if the currently logged in user is not the author of the post. Django REST + simpleJWT

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can i change my `postDetails` view, in order to allow only the author of the post (currently logged in user) the option of PUT and DELETE a post made by him?

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def postDetails(request, pk):

    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'message': 'The post does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        postData = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=postData)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        post.delete()
        return Response({'message': 'post was deleted successfully!'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_body = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access logged in user by `request.user`.
So this code checks if user is author of post. If user is not post's author, it returns `Response` with 403 status code(Forbidden):

```py
post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
if request.user != post.post_author:
    return Response(
        {'message': "you do not have permission to do this action"},
        status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    )
```